# What is the general ablaut rule that explains examples like φρήν, πρόφρων, πρόφρονα?

Tags: morphology, adjective, ancient-greek, third-declension

Φρήν (midriff, will) gives rise to the adjective πρόφρων (eager, literally motivated by will). It looks to me like the -ων comes from ablaut applied to -ην. (It doesn't look like a suffix -ων, since ν is already present in the noun. It's not a comparative -ων, and it also doesn't look like or decline like a participle. It also doesn't look like a person-who-has construction, since those form nouns, not adjectives.) The accusative is πρόφρονα. A similar example seems to be ἀπάτωρ. Summarizing:

πατήρ ἀπάτωρ ἀπάτορα

φρήν πρόφρων πρόφρονα

I'm sure there are discussions of this somewhere, but I can't seem to find anything relevant in Pharr or Smyth or by googling. It seems like there might be a rule that when a third-declension noun ends in a syllable with accented ή, and we form a third-declension adjective by prefixing it with a preposition, then we get the pattern shown above with ablaut and a receding accent, which seems to be the [paradigm of  κακοδαίμων](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Ancient_Greek_adjective_declension_tables#Nu) (possessed).

Is this rule correct? Does it only work with η? Only with accented η? Only with adjectives formed in this way out of a noun prefixed with a preposition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

φρήν, stem φρεν-, reflects a Proto-Indo-European root (straightforwardly **bʰren-*, though **gʷʰren-* has also been posited) in the e-grade, -φρων, stem -φρον-, has the same root in the o-grade. In both cases here the vowel is lengthened due to [Szemerényi's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szemer%C3%A9nyi%27s_law), a PIE sound law which holds that *-VRs > *-VːR—that is, if a vowel is followed by a resonant and an *-s* at the end of a word, the *-s* is lost and the vowel is lengthened; the -s in this case is the masculine nominative singular ending. Szemerényi's law is also why πατήρ has its η, and you can tell the lengthening must be old because ε/ο become η/ω rather than ει/ου, as they would in the historical period.

φρήν is/reflects a straightforward root noun, and it having the e-grade is not unusual. The o-grade in -φρων is pretty common in adjectives, and may be conditioned by the accent moving to the preceding syllable. The details are not necessarily well-understood, but they're details belonging to Proto-Indo-European, not Greek. The ablaut here (and indeed anywhere in Greek roots) is certainly **not a productive mechanism in Greek** anymore, and trying to read too much into it is not likely to be helpful to you.